# Trying to calculate quartiles but get java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, math, statistics

I'm trying to calculate the three quartiles (upper, middle and lower) of an array in java (Android Studio) But with the code below I get this error: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=-1` on line #9. This is then because of some operation I try to do with the length variable, but wrongly. Also if anyone has a better solution, or tip for how to calculate the upper, middle and lower quartiles in java array it would be much appreciated.

```
static double getLQ(double[] val) {

    Arrays.sort(val);

    int length = val.length;
    double LQ = 0;

    if(length % 2 != 0) {
        LQ = val[length / 4] + val[length / 2 - 1] / 2;
    } else {
        LQ = val[length / 4];
    }

    return LQ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically we cannot find quartiles when the number of elements is less than 4. Therefore we should handle that case first. Another thing is an array index starts from zero and we need to use brackets to work calculation according to the order we expect. Then if-else block would be as bellow.

```
 if (length < 4) {
    LQ = 0;
 } else if(length % 2 != 0) {
    LQ = (val[(length / 4) - 1] + val[length / 4]) / 2;
 } else {
    LQ = val[(length / 4) - 1];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one element, then `length / 2` resolves to `0` (because it's cut to `int`) and `length / 2 - 1` resolves to `-1`. Array indexing starts from 0:

```
if (length == 1) {
    LQ = val[0];
} else if(length % 2 != 0) {
    LQ = val[length / 4] + val[length / 2 - 1] / 2;
} else {
    LQ = val[length / 4];
}
```

Additional check whether the array is not empty would also be needed.